# Using ReactJS to create print page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There has got to be a less brute force way of making a print page then the way I have been doing it. (See below code).  Maybe with ReactJS and DOM insertions in some manner since the rest of my website is written with ReactJS? (See second example below)  I have tried using the CSS @media print, but it does not work well on very complex websites in all the browser flavors.  More recently, I have been making an entirely separate ReactJS website just for the print page and then passing it query strings for some of the information required on the print page.  What a mess that makes!

```
  var html: string = '<!DOCTYPE html>';

  html += '<html lang="en">';

  html += '<head>';
  html += '<meta charset="utf-8">';
  html += '<title>Title</title>';
  html += '</head>';

  html += '<body style="background-color: white;">';
  html += '<div">';
  html += getContent();
  html += '</div>';
  html += '</body>';
  html += '</html>';

  var newWin = window.open();
  newWin.document.write(html);
  newWin.document.close();
```

Second example:

```
  var sNew = document.createElement("script");
  sNew.async = true;
  sNew.src = "Bundle.js?ver=" + Date.now();
  var s0 = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s0.parentNode.insertBefore(sNew, s0);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yeah there is, checkout [react-print](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-print).

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var PrintTemplate = require ('react-print');

class MyTemplate extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
          <PrintTemplate>
             <div>
                  <h3>All markup for showing on print</h3>
                  <p>Write all of your "HTML" (really JSX) that you want to show
                  on print, in here</p>
                  <p>If you need to show different data, you could grab that data
                  via AJAX on componentWill/DidMount or pass it in as props</p>
                  <p>The CSS will hide the original content and show what is in your
                  Print Template.</p>
             </div>
           </PrintTemplate>
       )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyTemplate/>, document.getElementById('print-mount'));
```

Comment: I have not had much luck with the @media print method of printing.  There always seems to be some part of a complicated website that shows through onto the print page, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: what if you still need the `document.getElementById('root')`?